wordpress website connect with "Newebpay Payment"(using Woocommerce, RYwoocommerce tool)
I have connected with Newebpay Payment using RYwoocommerce tools, but when I place order, it stops at the page of checkout/order-pay. It can't turn to credit card payment page.
I saw the error in console(checkout/order-pay):
jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: v._fadeIn is not a function

at d (jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.7.0-wc.9.3.3:14:6659)
at e.blockUI (jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.7.0-wc.9.3.3:14:373)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (2015/?key=wc_order_HKIVN8OXI3ApR:534:3)
at e (jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js:2:30244)
at t (jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js:2:30546)

My website has jquery-3.6.0.slim.min., but when I modify into jquery-3.6.0.min. in the [woocommerce/archived-product.php] and [woocommerce/single-product.php], the question still here.

Modifying the jQuery version or variant only for specific pages, does not sound like a good idea. If anything, you should do it across the whole project. Does the documentation of what you are using there, say anything about specific library requirements? Does the same error happen, when instead of your - presumably - custom theme, you switch to the current WP/WC default themes?
